# Microcontroller identification, 44-pin

Tags: microcontroller, identification

I am desperately seeking the real type of this branded 44-pin microcontroller.
Does anybody know this pinout?

I already checked many thousands of 44-pinners on Digikey and Mouser.

A 16MHz crystal is connected to pins 8 and 9.

There is a good chance it's a Japanese brand, the PCB is manufactured in this country. Already checked Renesas, Mitsubishi, NEC, Hitachi, and the rest.

Maybe pin 1 location is shifted to another corner?

[image]

Comment: From what device is this, and what is printed on the chip? It can very well be a standard µC with custom pinout or even a custom asic, especially if the device is from a manufacturer that does chip design too.

Comment: your eyes probably dealt with it more than my do with the foto: Is the printing "11XW1 629S71"?

Comment: Why are you so desperate? What do you intend to achieve if you knew? Answers to those questions will be essential to really understand the value of moving ahead with this. There are a plethora of reasons why knowing will be next to fruitless.

Comment: Thx for the informations already, the printing is "11XW1/629S7d". But that seems to be custom specific printed. Some other chips on the PCB look similar branded. I could not find any informations on this branding in the net.

Comment: I think it is a standard micro. It is from a PC interface to a niche  automation product and I think the number of produced devices are to small for a custom chip.

Comment: I have found the same chip in a shimano E6000 switch. it only has 2 wires for power and data. I am now just searching for info on the net.
What I found is I have 11XW1 at the top for chip number and 631S2h at the bottom.
I think its a datecode at the bottom: 2016 week 31 and for you: 2016 week 29.
Mine is a tiny 4 or more layer PCB. reverse engineering this will be a nightmare.

Comment: It could be a no name chip out of China. There are a lot now days, for sure if this is a low cost device.

Comment: What country is "this country"? StackExchange has an international audience.